# Issue in collapsible section SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages, collapsible-sections

I have an issue in the collapsible section in SharePoint online.

I'm trying to add a new section in a site page and whenever I try to edit it in order to add a title in the text field of the collapsible section, the text field take my input.

In other words, whenever the collapsible section title is clicked, no cursor is shown to input a text, instead the section only collapse.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this issue at my end. I am not able to change the section title of existing collapsible sections as well as not able to add title to newly created collapsible sections.

Other people are also facing the exact same issues. Check these threads:

1. [SharePoint: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/07/01/sharepoint-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages) - check comments section
2. [Techcommunity - SharePoint Online: Collapsible sections on modern pages](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-collapsible-sections-on-modern-pages/m-p/2510198/page/3)

I will recommend to raise a support ticket with Microsoft, check [Get Online support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Comment: Thank you @Ganeshsanap for your reply. Yes that's what i did yesterday and today i have a call with Microsoft support. If thay gave me a feasible solution i will let you know.

Comment: Thanks, please keep us updated. Probably support team will take a note of the issue, report it to technical/development team and will release the fix in next update.